# Freemarker Template - User Session context

Tags: freemarker

Will the Freemarker Template support user session similar to JSP?

Can we read and write to user session?

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker itself doesn't care about things like sessions, HTTP requests and the like. It just receives a bunch of objects via the data-model, and then it can access those. So it's up to the web application framework what the templates can do. Modifying a session in an MVC template really smells though. That's the duty of the MVC Controller.

However, if you are using `FreemarkerServlet`, that creates a data-model that exposes the variables from the request, session and application scopes, and also provides `Request`, `Session`, `Application` variables to read the specific scopes. Though `FreemarkerServlet` is really just an adapter for legacy or JSP-only apps, otherwise I would avoid it.